# What happens if a java flyway migration throws an exception?

Tags: java, flyway

I was wondering how Flyway handles exceptions thrown from classes that implement the JdbcMigration interface.

Does Flyway roll back the transaction? Does it stop doing further migrations?

Comment: Yes, it will rollback the transaction until the latest well executed script or latest commit done. Then it will log the Exception and notify you (depending how you configure it).

Comment: This might be helpful :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4959299/how-to-roll-back-migrations-using-flyway/4959332#4959332

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Your comment is correct. Turn it into an answer.

Comment: All I know is that I had to clean several "exceptions" from flyway migration off my car windshield this morning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does Flyway roll back the transaction?

Yes, it will rollback the transaction until the latest well executed script or latest commit done. Then it will log the Exception and notify you (depending how you configure it).

> Does it stop doing further migrations?

AFAIK that's the common behavior, it will stop if it encounters an error.

Comment: Aren't most DBs unable to do rollback on more than one DDL statement? How will Flyway deal with a script that's had only half its statements executed?

Comment: @AleksandrDubinsky it is like an atomic operation: all or nothing, per script, unless you modify that configuration.

Comment: From MySQL docs: "Some statements cannot be rolled back. In general, these include data definition language (DDL) statements, such as those that create or drop databases, those that create, drop, or alter tables or stored routines." Ie, any transaction with such a statement can't be rolled back. Some DBs do support DDL transactions (eg PostgreSQL). Others support a single DDL statement per transaction. Liquibase opens a transaction per statement and records it in the metadata, which may help (it knows where it left off). For Flyway, it sounds like you'd better recover the DB from a snapshot.